# Windows 7 Boots up fine in Safe mode with Network, Normal Bootup just shows black screen with cursor How to troubleshoot?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

As the title says, I get a black screen with a cursor.

If I boot into safemode with networking, all is fine.

I've disabled all startup items in msconfig, but not sure what I should do next. Any suggesstions?

Other things I tried at black screen:
ctrl alt del
ctrl shift esc

Mouse cursor moves around fine

Comment: How long did you wait?

Comment: Try it in VGA mode.  This behavior can sometimes be seen when the monitor is treated like the extended desktop.

Comment: is the start menu present?

Comment: Waited over 6 hours, I tried switching the video mode and hooking up to an external monitor, and the Start menu is not present.

Comment: Can you remove your video drivers in safe mode? Then either use vanilla Windows drivers or reinstall your graphics card drivers (if you can do both, in that order trying to boot normal in between)

Comment: Clearly some Windows system files are corrupt. From within Safe Mode restore your system to an earlier time when Windows starts as expected...